# Value is undefined when element is obtained with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code where I obtain my input element with jQuery:

```
var txt = $(tableRow).find('input:text');
if (txt.value == null) {
  //TO DO code
}
```

and here's how I do it with pure JavaScript

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txtAge');
if (txt.value == null) {
  //TO DO code
}
```

With the first way the value of the txt is undefined. But with the second way the value is what's inside the input element. Now more interesting is, on the bottom-right pane of the Mozilla Firebug  if I scroll down to the "value" of the txt I can see it there, both ways.

I know I can simply say `$(txt).val()`, but I also want to understand why I can't access the value of an element if it's been selected by jQuery. Isn't jQuery just a library of JavaScript functions?

Comment: `.value` is not a property of a jQuery object it's a property of DOM elements. jQuery is some kind of a wrapper around the DOM API, but it does not map the DOM API 1:1.

Comment: @FelixKling rasdif ht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` will return an arry-like object. If you're sure that there's one, and one only, element matching your query, you could do

```
var txt = $(tableRow).find('input:text')[0].value;
```

That's not very jQuery-like, so to speak, more like a mismatch of both jQuery and DOM methods, but it'll get what you want. Also, since you show, as a DOM example, `var txt = document.getElementById('txtAge');`, this could be rewritten in jQuery as

`var txt = $('#txtAge')[0];`

Comment: This is the exact answer to my case

Answer (score 6):

`.value` is not part of the jquery api. You should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead:

```
var txt = $(tableRow).find('input:text');
if (txt.val() == "") {
  //TO DO code
}
```

A dom object and a jquery dom object are not exactly the same. In fact, you can open the Developer tools (in webkit) or Firebug (Firefox) to check what are they in the inside. Jquery holds more information (actually, it contains an instance of the dom that it's representing). So, if you wanted to use `.value`, you need to call the "generic" dom object from the jquery object, and then use `.value`.

Comment: So, $('#inputElement') and document.getElementById('inputElement') return different things? How? Doesn't it just go and grab the element in the document? This is the first time I've gotten disappointed by jQuery after all those miracles it did for me.

Comment: But `$('#inputElement')[0]` and `document.getElementById('inputElement')` are the same object.

Comment: Note that jQuery’s `.val()` never returns `null`.

Comment: All the answers are appreciated but @Samuel Caillerie's comment wide opened my eyes. I'm amazed. Thank you man. I've just realized that from $.find I get an array. Please post this as an aswer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Mike: `$(...)` returns a jQuery object and it's only because of that it can do all this magic. A jQuery object is basically a collection of DOM elements and provides all the methods with which you can interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selects DOM elements using various native and non-native techniques and places them all in it’s own array-like instance that also wraps them in their own API. jQuery doesn’t "extend" native DOM properties or methods, so you will need to target the DOM node to do that.

Think of it like this:

```
var node = document.getElementById('txtAge'); // the DOM node
var txt = $('#txtAge'); // the same node wrapped in a jQuery object/API
```

Since jQuery object holds an array-like collection of DOM nodes, so you can access the first element by doing:

```
txt[0] // same as node
```

But it’s generally recommended that you use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
txt.get(0)
```

Another more jQuery-way to do what you want is to iterate through a jQuery collection using `.each()`:

```
$(tableRow).find('input:text').each(function() {
    // "this" in the each callback is the DOM node
    if ( this.value == null ) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = $(tableRow).find('input:text');
```

It's an jquery object .

```
`x.value`
```

There is no property value in jquery object . So it returns undefined.

`x.val()` is a method you can use for get the value of an element.